# How to Upload Multiple Images in php using function

Tags: php, html

HTML form to select multiple images.
Upload images to the server using PHP.
HTML:

```html
<div style="margin-left:15%; margin-top:10%">

  <form action="image-post-process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  />

     <table width="500px" align="center" bgcolor="blueskay">

        <tr align="center">

           <td colspan="2"><h2>Update Your Account</h2></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

             <td align="right">Customer Image:</td>

             <td><input type="file" name="image[]" multiple /></td>

        </tr>

        <tr align="center">

             <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Account"/></td>

             <td></td>

        </tr>
 
     </table>

   </form>

</div>
```

File upload in PHP is the most used functionality for the web application. A single file or multiple files can be easily uploaded using PHP. PHP provides a quick and simple way to implement server-side file upload functionality. Generally, in the web application, the file is uploaded to the server and the file name is stored in the database. Later the files are retrieved from the server based on the file name stored in the database.
PHP:

```php
#image-post-process.php

function imageFunction($imageName, $imageSize, $imageTmp)

{

  $ext = pathinfo($imageName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  $allwoed_extention = array('pdf', 'png', 'jpg','JPEG','PNG','GIF','jpeg','JPG','PDF','docx');

  if(in_array($ext, $allwoed_extention)){

    if ($imageSize < 10485760) {

      $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) ."_".$imageSize."_".$imageName;

      move_uploaded_file($imageTmp, "image/".$newfilename);

      return $newfilename;

    }else{

      echo "File Size Not Match";

    }

  }else{

    echo "Extension Not Match";

  }

}

$count = count($_FILES['image']['name']);

for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) 

{ 

$imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];

$imageSize = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];

$imageTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];


imageFunction($imageName, $imageSize, $imageTmp);

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I think you need to make every image think it is part of a group. so after declaring your function, you can include a "foreach"

```
foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name) {// more code goes in here}
```